# How to use Math.max and Max.min functions in an Array?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I tried this method in an array to get min and max values but it doesn't work.

```
var array = [3, 6, 1, 5, 0, -2, 3];
var min = Math.min( array ); 
var max = Math.max( array ); 
document.write(max);
```

Comment: Declare array,min and max as int

Answer (score 4):

Use [`Function.apply`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply)

```
min = Math.min.apply(null, array);
min = Math.max.apply(null, array);
```

> `apply` is very similar to [`call()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call), except for the type of arguments it
>   supports. You can use an arguments array instead of a named set of
>   parameters. With `apply`, you can use an array literal

Comment: i try this but not working

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```js
function minmax(){
  var max = Math.max.apply(Math, arguments);
  var min = Math.min.apply(Math, arguments);
  console.log(max);  // print 6
  console.log(min); // print -2
}
minmax (3, 6, 1, 5, 0, -2, 3);
```